# Monotouch and locale issue

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I am in the process of localizing my application.  Everything works well except one issue.  According to the Apple docs, if you have a specific region, it should be selected first and then to the more general.   So for instance, in my project, I have:

en.lproj

```
Localization.strings
```

en_US.lproj

```
Localization.strings
```

While I am set to US English in my settings, Monotouch is picking the en.lproj before en_US.lproj when it should be the other way around.  Is this a bug or is this not supported?

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848566/does-ios-look-for-region-specific-lproj-directory-e-g-en-us-lproj) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, that link helped.   And I re-read the docs and it does not work that way I thought on iOS, only OSX.   So iOS only looks at locale only eg. en.lproj.